# react-pdf-js - Uncaught (in promise) e {name: "InvalidPDFException", message: "Invalid PDF structure"}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I have intentionally (to minimize any errors at first) only copied the [demo for react-pdf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js), added `page` and `pages` in the `state` to resolve an error, added the closing `);` at the end of the `render/return` to resolve another error, and edited the component name.  Still, I am getting the error below and am unsure of what it means.  It points to the first line of `viewingPDF` (which is my html extension `myapp.firebaseapp.com/viewingPDF`) so it isn't directly pointing to anything wrong in my component and I'm unsure how to fix it.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
e
message: "Invalid PDF structure"
name : "InvalidPDFException"
__proto__ : Error at https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:3985 at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:4013) at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:12954) at t (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27623) at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:56:12712) at t (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27623) at re (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:28006) at https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:28016 at n.(anonymous function).i (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27496) at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27500)
stack: "Error↵    at https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:3985↵    at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:4013)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:34:12954)↵    at t (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27623)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:56:12712)↵    at t (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27623)↵    at re (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:28006)↵    at https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:28016↵    at n.(anonymous function).i (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27496)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/static/js/main.9108db74.js:33:27500)"
__proto__: Object
constructor: Error()
message: ""
name: "Error"
toString: toString()
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()
constructor: Object()
hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: toLocaleString()
toString: toString()
valueOf: valueOf()
get __proto__: __proto__()
set __proto__: __proto__()
```

**This is my component implementation (kept close to the demo above):**

```
import React from 'react';
import PDF from 'react-pdf-js';

class ViewPDF extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      pages: 3
    }
    this.onDocumentComplete = this.onDocumentComplete.bind(this);
    this.onPageComplete = this.onPageComplete.bind(this);
    this.handlePrevious = this.handlePrevious.bind(this);
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
  }

  onDocumentComplete(pages) {
    this.setState({ page: 1, pages });
  }

  onPageComplete(page) {
    this.setState({ page });
  }

  handlePrevious() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  }

  handleNext() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  }

  renderPagination(page, pages) {
    let previousButton = <li className="previous" onClick={this.handlePrevious}><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</a></li>;
    if (page === 1) {
      previousButton = <li className="previous disabled"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</a></li>;
    }
    let nextButton = <li className="next" onClick={this.handleNext}><a href="#">Next <i className="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></li>;
    if (page === pages) {
      nextButton = <li className="next disabled"><a href="#">Next <i className="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></li>;
    }
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul className="pager">
          {previousButton}
          {nextButton}
        </ul>
      </nav>
      );
  }

  render() {
    let pagination = null;
    if (this.state.pages) {
      pagination = this.renderPagination(this.state.page, this.state.pages);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <PDF file="somefile.pdf" onDocumentComplete={this.onDocumentComplete} onPageComplete={this.onPageComplete} page={this.state.page} />
        {pagination}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ViewPDF;
```

In an effort to strip the code down to the bare basics and just get a pdf rendering, I alternatively reduced my component down to the following.  Still, I get the same error.

**Alternative (reduced to basics):**

```
import React from 'react';
import PDF from 'react-pdf-js';

export default class ViewPDF extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      pages: 3
    };

    this.onDocumentComplete = this.onDocumentComplete.bind(this);
    this.onPageComplete = this.onPageComplete.bind(this);
  }

  onDocumentComplete(pages) {
    this.setState({ page: 1, pages });
  }

  onPageComplete(page) {
    this.setState({ page });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PDF file="somePdfToView.pdf"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Invalid PDF Structure".. I'm pretty sure the demo has taken some liberties with that file reference (`<PDF file="somePdfToView.pdf"/>`). See [react-pdf#props](https://github.com/nnarhinen/react-pdf#props) for what it should be.

Comment: you nailed it! Thanks!  Swapping out the simple path for an import statment at the top of my component (such as `import myPDF from '../static/sample.pdf'`) and then replacing `<PDF file="somePdfToView.pdf"/>` with `<PDF file={myPDF}"/>` worked beautifully.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Rbar How did you get the import to work?  I am trying to do `import myPDF from '../myPDF.pdf'` as well, but mine says it can't find the module.